# Python + Selenium Randomly Closing

Tags: python, selenium

Back with another problem. It runs until the bottom "click_next_page"(doesn't click the button) and it randomly ends the driver with 0 error codes. It was working fine yesterday. Can anyone see a problem? First time I'm working with Python so I don't know how to troubleshoot this. Thanks in advance!

```
from random import randint
import time

from decouple import config
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha
from twocaptcha.api import ApiException, NetworkException
from twocaptcha.solver import ValidationException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome ("C:/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://10minutesemail.net/")

time.sleep(2)

Copy_Email = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "copyEmailAddress"))).click()

time.sleep(5)

driver.execute_script("window.open('https://quora.com/','_blank')")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

click_register = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div)[34]"))).click()

name = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "profile-name"))).send_keys("Jackson Fuller")
email = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "email")))
act = ActionChains(driver)
act.send_keys(Keys.TAB).perform()
act.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("V").key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()

click_next = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div)[44]"))).click()

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

click_email = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "mail-open"))).click()

switch_email_frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@class='w-100 border-0']")))
double_click_code = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/div")))
act.double_click(double_click_code).perform()
act.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("C").key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
time.sleep(5)
act.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("V").key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()

click_next_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div)[70]"))).click()

type_password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"password"))).send_keys("Password1")
```

**EDIT**

So I commented out these imports and it started to work even though they were not being used in the code anywhere. What would be the cause of this? I appreciate all the answers.

```
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha
from twocaptcha.api import ApiException, NetworkException
from twocaptcha.solver import ValidationException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from decouple import config
from random import randint
```

Comment: Where is _**click_next_page**_? What are the manual steps to repro the issue?

Comment: Quora.com>Register>Name and Email> Then it asks for the verification code after putting in the code it doesn't click Next it just closes. Weird because it worked fine yesterday.

Comment: click_next = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div)[44]"))).click() seems like a bad xpath to use. Can you post the html of the element in question.

Comment: I found the solution but I don't know what has caused it. I will edit my main post, anyone know why this happens?